# What is the message of geometry_msgs/PoseWithCovariance

Tags: ros-kinetic, ubuntu, ubuntu-xenial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I'm using ROS kinetic in ubuntu 16.04 and still think I'm new to ROS.

Anyway, I'm making some packages above on people tracking so I need to estimate people's state and their covariance in 2D circumstance.

And I found the ROS message of geometry_msgs/PoseWithCovariance and geometry_msgs/TwistWithCovariance.

These covariance terms have 36-length of a list, so I think they correspond to [x, y, z, roll, pitch, yaw] terms row and column each other.

The problem is I have no idea how to access them. When I'm gonna get the value of (row 3, col 4), where is it? Is it CUSTOMIZED_MSG_NAME.covarianve[15] ?

In other words,  when I inspect from  CUSTOMIZED_MSG_NAME.covarianve[0] to [5], is these values correspond to the all first row of the covariance matrix(list in ROS message) ?? or column ??

Thanks in advance :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/334500/what-is-the-message-of-geometry_msgs/posewithcovariance/) by [kane_choigo](https://answers.ros.org/users/45263/kane_choigo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 195 on 2019-10-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Considering that the first row and column are 0, row 3, column 4 (roll pitch covariance) will be index 29. If you are considering that first row and column are 1, then row 3, column 4 (z roll covariance) will be index 21.

ROS uses a row/column indexation of columns to vectors. So 0 to 5 corresponds to the first row.

---

Originally posted by [lucascoelho](https://answers.ros.org/users/1016/lucascoelho/) with karma: 497 on 2019-10-03

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on 2019-10-04**:
Not to be zealous, I just want to correct you because confusions with this are easy to make but hard to debug sometimes :

> Considering that the first row and column are 0

It's not a consideration. The first index of an array is 0 so the first row and column are 0 too (which is matching with the formulas below).

I don't know how you got the value 29 and 21, you probably have also considered that the first index is 1, but you can have x (row number) and y (column number) from those formulas :

```
y = index % columns_number = 29 % 6 = 5
x = (index -  index % columns_number)/columns_number = (29 - y)/6 = 4
```

So 29 is actually row 4 column 5 and 21 is row 3 column 3.
Index is calculated as @lmathieu said in his comment :

```
index = x * columns_number + y
```

**Comment by [lucascoelho](https://answers.ros.org/users/1016/lucascoelho/) on 2019-10-04**:
Indeed, my indexes are all wrong! Sorry for that.
But my consideration about the first index is because on linear algebra textbooks and Matlab, the first index is 1, so I wanted to make things clear before proceeding.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello !

The documentation for this message is [here](http://docs.ros.org/api/geometry_msgs/html/msg/PoseWithCovariance.html):

> ```
> # This represents a pose in free space with uncertainty.
> ```

```
Pose pose
```

> 

```
# Row-major representation of the 6x6 covariance matrix
# The orientation parameters use a fixed-axis representation.
# In order, the parameters are:
# (x, y, z, rotation about X axis, rotation about Y axis, rotation about Z axis)
float64[36] covariance
```

So `covariance` is [Row-Major](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-_and_column-major_order) order so you can access it with 2 methods :

```
CUSTOMIZED_MSG_NAME.covariance[0..35]
```

or

```
CUSTOMIZED_MSG_NAME.covariance[0*6+0..5*6+5]  (for 6*6 matrix only)
```

<del>CUSTOMIZED_MSG_NAME.covariance[0..5][0..5]</del>

---

Originally posted by [lmathieu](https://answers.ros.org/users/30984/lmathieu/) with karma: 591 on 2019-10-03

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kane_choigo](https://answers.ros.org/users/45263/kane_choigo/) on 2019-10-03**:
Hello!

Thanks for your quick response. So, is that means there would NOT be any other problems when I access it like '  CUSTOMIZED_MSG_NAME.covariance[2][3] = VARIABLE_1'? Is it NOT necessary to write it like 'CUSTOMIZED_MSG_NAME.covariance[15] '?

**Comment by [lmathieu](https://answers.ros.org/users/30984/lmathieu/) on 2019-10-04**:
And i'm sorry but no, you cannot actually use the [][] on cpp std::vector/boost::array or python tuple (the deserialized type http://wiki.ros.org/msg)

Actually only the first version is ok.
what you can do is :

CUSTOMIZED_MSG_NAME.covariance[X*N+Y],  where N is the size of your square matrix (6 here), X the row and Y the column.(0-indexed)
See the other answers

**Comment by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on 2019-10-04**:\

> where N is the size of your square matrix (6 here)

Just to be accurate : `N` is the columns number, the size of the matrix is `36`